# Using present time of video to manage all video in Action Script 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, flash-video, adobe-flash-cs3

I would like to use present time of video to manage all video. For example, I have some cue points, I choose it and video is now playing from this cue point, and after 10 sec video goes to other part and everything depends on present time of video. I do not use it on web so my video isn't loading (I mean that property of VideoProgressEvent like bytesLoaded will not help me). Is it possible to do it in action script 3.0 ? Another question is if I can add some transitions between cue points.

```
    import fl.video.*;

// Video component instance name
var flvControl:FLVPlayback = display;
var flvSource:String = "myMovie.flv";

// Set video
flvControl.source = flvSource;



var myTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
myTextFormat.size = 20
btn1.setStyle("textFormat", myTextFormat);
btn2.setStyle("textFormat", myTextFormat);
btn3.setStyle("textFormat", myTextFormat);
btn4.setStyle("textFormat", myTextFormat);
display.autoPlay = false;


// Add seek to time code
function seekToTimeHandler1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   var sec:Number = 15;
   flvControl.seek(sec);
}
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, seekToTimeHandler1);

// Add seek to time code
function seekToTimeHandler2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   var sec:Number = 61;
   flvControl.seek(sec);
}
btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, seekToTimeHandler2);

// Add seek to time code         
function seekToTimeHandler3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   var sec:Number = 63;
   flvControl.seek(sec);
}
btn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, seekToTimeHandler3);

// Add seek to time code
function seekToTimeHandler4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   var sec:Number = 80;
   flvControl.seek(sec);
}
btn4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, seekToTimeHandler4);
```

Comment: What do you mean by : "Using present time of video to manage all video" ? Could you explain more what's the problem and what do you want to do ?

Comment: I mean that cue point goes to for example 0:45 and when video progress is 1:00 then automatically goes to another part of video for example 0:20 without any user action.